# Stopping Manifold from writing TMP files?

Tags: performance, manifold

We work with sizable Manifold Projects that sometimes go over a Gb of vector data. After working in Manifold for a while Gigs of TMP files are getting written to the hard drive.

We use manifold 8 64 bit - so we would have assumed everything was done in memory as that's what 64 bit's great for!

Is there anyway to stop this? We're running 12Gb x64 Windows 7 machines and there's got to be a performance hit in there...  Plus our sysadmins aren't too fond of the Gigs of TMP files we leave lying around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure temp folders on a separate, fast hard disk

Create a .bat file which starts when manifold starts to delete .tmp files after 5,10 mins
only released (not locked/used) .tmp files will be deleted.

http://www.manifold.net/doc/optimizing_performance.htm

Comment: Thanks - I feared it was a case of managing the TMP files, as opposed to eliminating the need for them (like turning undo off or something like that).  I'm tempted to try out a RAM disk but Manifold sometimes leaves TMP files in the directory of the project file... So it may not be a cure-all.